# clojure core.tools.cli: How to override boolean option?

Tags: clojure, command-line-interface

I want a command that takes arguments which look like this:

```
--enable-boolean-flag --disable-boolean-flag --enable-boolean-flag
```

In the `:options` key returned by `clojure.tools.cli/parse-opts`, I want to have the `:boolean-flag` option set to true if the `--enable-boolean-flag` option came last on the command line and false if `--disable-boolean-flag` came last on the command line, if that makes any sense.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I'm using 0.3.6 of the `core.tools.cli` library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by taking advantage of `:id`, `:default`, and `:assoc-fn` properties that tools-cli lets you specify for each command line option.

- Use `:id` to set the same id for "--enable" and "--disable" options
- Use `:default` on one of the options to specify what you want to happen if neither "--enable" or "--disable" are specified
- Use `:assoc-fn` to specify what effect the option has on the options map. You want the value set to `false` every time "--disable" appears and to `true` every time `--enable` appears.

Putting it all together:

```
(ns clis.core
  (:require [clojure.tools.cli :refer [parse-opts]])
  (:gen-class))

(def cli-options
  [["-e" "--enable" "Enable"
    :default true
    :id :boolean-flag
    :assoc-fn (fn [m k _] (assoc m k true))]
   ["-d" "--disable" "Disable"
    :id :boolean-flag
    :assoc-fn (fn [m k _] (assoc m k false))]])

(defn -main [& args]
  (parse-opts args cli-options))
```

Testing at the REPL:

```
(-main)
;; {:options {:boolean-flag true}, :arguments [], :summary "  -e, --enable   Enable\n  -d, --disable  Disable", :errors nil}
(-main "-e" "-d" "-e")
;; {:options {:boolean-flag true}, :arguments [], :summary "  -e, --enable   Enable\n  -d, --disable  Disable", :errors nil}
(-main "-e" "-d" "-e" "-d")
;; {:options {:boolean-flag false}, :arguments [], :summary "  -e, --enable   Enable\n  -d, --disable  Disable", :errors nil}
```

Comment: Using the same ID throws an error, no? I thought IDs had to be unique per argument.

Comment: That is not the case. The code I included works. Also, see the [docstring for parse-opts](https://github.com/clojure/tools.cli/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/tools/cli.clj#L498). It specifically says that multiple option entries can share the same `:id`